# XAML Is there a way to bind an Event to a Method using Style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using style to define the template of a predefined control. The control is part of a Framework which I cannot modify. This control has a `DataGrid` and for that I want to add a `MouseDoubleClick` event. The event handler (`HandleGridDoubleClick`) is already specified in the framework.

Is there a way to bind to this method ? I understand it would have been easy if the Framework provided a Command for that.

```
<Style
    TargetType="xyz:FileMessageControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate
                TargetType="xyz:FileMessageControl">
                   <Grid>
                    .....
                       <DataGrid MouseDoubleClick = HandleGridDoubleClick>
                        .....
                       </DataGrid>
                   </Grid>
           </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (you need to use Interaction dll)

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>                            
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
        <action:ExecuteCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.HandleGridDoubleClick}" />
     </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the best way to do it but unfortunately I just noticed that the method is set to private. In that case, I guess this won't work.